# How to share all files and folders over the network

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing

I was wondering how to share all my files on my win 7 machine with my win 10 machine over the network.

Comment: This can be quite dangerous if you don't trust the other people on your network. (I'm assuming you want to share the full contents of all drives.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the root directory of another machine using the following syntax:

```
\\Another-Machine\C$
\\Another-Machine\D$
etc.
```

Comment: This assumes that you've set up identical accounts on both the source and target systems, and those accounts are in each local PCs "Administrators" group. Also, these shares won't show up when browsing the network (i.e., when you go to \\Another-Machine in Windows Explorer, you won't see C$ or D$); you'd need to type in the UNC to get to it.